# php shell_exec casperJS

Tags: php, linux

I installed the phantomJS and casperJS on my linux machine and add symbolic links in the /usr/local/bin/casperjs and /usr/local/bin/phantomjs. if I login via ssh all is working perfect.

but I want to call casperjs in a php script with shell_exec:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs');
```

I also added to my php include_path:
.:/usr/local/bin/casperjs

but I get only "NULL" as output from the exec command - how could this be done? could anyone help? how can I use casperjs within the webhost directory which is in /var/www/?

Comment: I think it happens because `casperjs` spawns a new child and returns instantly

Comment: Try using `exec()` and `var_dump()` to see what returns.

`shell_exec()` returns `NULL` when there is any kind of problem executing.